# Friis transmission equation: antenna gains

Tags: android, wifi

I'm trying to determin the distance ,with the Friis equation :
[image]

where G t and G r are the antenna gains. I would like to know how to determine  the Gt and the Gr in general ?I'm using Wi-Fi. And in my case the transmitter is the Access point and the receiver is an android mobile, how can i know them ,are the Gt and the Gr constants ?

PS: I'm working in free space.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.moxa.com/newsletter/connection/2008/03/Figure_out_transmission_distance_from_wireless_device_specs.htm

Comment: Thank you for replying. Well in this example they took the two gains= 2 dBi. From where did they took this value ,is it prescripted in the device spec ? @Sree

Comment: they are using IEEE 802.11 wireless AP/Bridge/Client so the value set like that, please read from the basic so that you will get more idea on this,

Answer (score 1):

Usually for a simple router, the antenna is a dipole so its gain would be 1.65 or 2.15dBi. In case of the cell phone the antenna gain would be similar to the dipole or lower. It can be simply taken as 1 or 0dBi.